# I need help Identifying if I've made a mistake in either html or php code snippet

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to pass some values to a php file from an html file by using a `<form action="addExp.php">` tag. The two variables I want to pass is the "`catGory`" and the "`amount`" values.

Everytime It succesfully directs me to the `addExp.php` page but it doesn't there always seem to be some error displayed in the browser's console:

[image]

My html code:

```
<form action="addExp.php">
    <div style="position: fixed;" id="Cat">
      <select name="catGory" id="catSelect">
        <option hidden disabled selected value=''>Select a Category</option>
        <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
        <option value="Health">Health</option>
        <option value="Groceries">Groceries</option>
        <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
        <option value="Travelling">Travelling</option>
        <option value="Education">Education</option>
        <option value="Work">Work</option>
        <option value="Bills/Taxes">Bills/Taxes</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" step="0.01" id="amount" name="amount">
</form>
```

My "addExp.php" code:

```
  <?php
  //phpinfo();  //Uncomment to check php info

  //Declare the variables that will receive the payment infos
  $inAmount = $_POST['amount'];
  $trnCat = $_POST['catGory'];


  //variables that define the connection to the database
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "rahim";
  $password = "**********";
  $dBase = "Users";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dBase);


  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  //Check if the Expense table exists or no
  $val = $conn->prepare('select 1 from `Expenses` LIMIT 1');

  //Create Table query first 
  $sQuer1 = "CREATE TABLE Expenses(
    Amount FLOAT(9,2),
    Category CHAR,
    pyDate Date, 
  )";


  //Execute addition of record into Table
  if ($val !== FALSE) //if the Table exists
  {
    //Prepare statement and parameters to be executed into the query
    $statmnt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Expenses (Amount,Category,pyDate) VALUES (?,?,?)"); //prepare SQL statement/query for execution
    $statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, date("l d-m")); //bind the selected parameters to the SQL statement   

    //Execute the query statement
    $statmnt -> execute();

    //show that data is added
    echo "Table exists, so data have been added";

  } else {
    //Create the table because table doesn't exist
    $conn->query($sQuer1);  // query() function performs a query against a database

    //Prepare statement and parameters to be executed into the query
    $statmnt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Expenses (Amount,Category,pyDate) VALUES (?,?,?)"); //prepare SQL statement/query for execution
    $statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, date("l d-m")); //bind the selected parameters to the SQL statement

    //Execute the query statement
    $statmnt -> execute();

    //show that table is created 
    echo "The Table has been creaetd";
  }

  ?>
```

Edit: I also forgot to show my apache2 error logs:
[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwlER.png)

Comment: Don't forget to change your password, here, and everywhere else that uses that password

Comment: And what's the point of the first query? You appear to do nothing with it.

Comment: Also, it's fantastically unlikely that a column called 'amount' in a table called 'expenses' would be FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented

Comment: And CHAR expects a length, otherwise is treated as char(1)

Comment: Also, take a look at `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` syntax

Comment: @Strawberry is the password still visible, i thought it's been blanked with stars

Comment: @Strawberry the first query is to create the table if it haven't been created yet, I did use it

Comment: @AbdulRahimMohamedSuhaimi The password is still visible in the revisions of the post. So yes, u'd better change it out

Comment: Unfortunately, anyone can view the thread history, so stars ain't gonna work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to set the form method to post to receive the parameters of post parameters

```
<form method="POST" action="addExp.php">
   <select name="catGory" id="catSelect"> 
    ...
```

...

set to submitted value (with check if that value actually exists for that key)

```
$trnCat = array_key_exists('catGory', $_POST) ? $_POST['catGory'] : false;
```

to see what the error is look at the response tab in inspector, if nothing ist display you could google for php error_reporting / debug log

or you wrap your code into

```
try {
  //your code
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and then look at response

Comment: I've checked my /var/log/apache2/error.log , and the error i'm getting is this:  [Thu Jan 28 17:08:58.354699 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 33452] [client 127.0.0.1:58448] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: amount in /var/www/FinancApp/addExp.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/addTrn.html
[Thu Jan 28 17:08:58.354765 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 33452] [client 127.0.0.1:58448] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: catGory in /var/www/FinancApp/addExp.php on line 7, referer: http://localhost/addTrn.html

Comment: there you go! If you change form method to POST the indicies should be found, check my update, you can check first whether the parameters are submitted so it does not throw error

Comment: oh but I do have one more slight problem, when I perform a "SELECT * FROM Expenses; " , it still shows an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

the error you are getting because its not finding table Expenses because there is an error in create table query

> $sQuer1 = "CREATE TABLE Expenses(
> Amount FLOAT(9,2),
> Category CHAR,
> pyDate Date,
> )";

a comma after Date and when i removed it to

> $sQuer1 = "CREATE TABLE Expenses(
> Amount FLOAT(9,2),
> Category CHAR,
> pyDate Date
> )";

Then its worked and creted table and other code also ruing, But when its executing got error on two lines

```
 $statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, date("l d-m"));
```

and

```
 $statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, date("l d-m"));
```

error i got on these two lines:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\stack\redirect\addExp.php on line 54

so i changed these two lines to

```
$dtt=date("l d-m");
$statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, $dtt );
```

and

```
$dt = date("l d-m");
$statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, $dt);
```

and its worked fine.

one more thing to receive data use $_GET else it may give error undefined variable.

here the complete code:

```
 <?php
//phpinfo();  //Uncomment to check php info

//Declare the variables that will receive the payment infos
$inAmount = $_GET['amount'];
$trnCat = $_GET['catGory'];


//variables that define the connection to the database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dBase = "deteled";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dBase);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Check if the Expense table exists or no
$val = $conn->prepare('select 1 from `Expenses` LIMIT 1');

//Create Table query first 
$sQuer1 = "CREATE TABLE Expenses(
Amount FLOAT(9,2),
Category CHAR,
pyDate Date
)";


//Execute addition of record into Table
if ($val !== FALSE) //if the Table exists
{
//Prepare statement and parameters to be executed into the query
$statmnt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Expenses (Amount,Category,pyDate) VALUES 
(?,?,?)"); //prepare SQL statement/query for execution
$dtt=date("l d-m");
$statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, $dtt ); //bind the selected parameters 
to the SQL statement   

//Execute the query statement
$statmnt -> execute();

//show that data is added
echo "Table exists, so data have been added";

} else {
//Create the table because table doesn't exist
$conn->query($sQuer1);  // query() function performs a query against a database

//Prepare statement and parameters to be executed into the query
$statmnt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Expenses (Amount,Category,pyDate) VALUES 
(?,?,?)"); //prepare SQL statement/query for execution
$dt = date("l d-m");
$statmnt->bind_param("dss", $inAmount, $trnCat, $dt); //bind the selected parameters 
to the SQL statement

//Execute the query statement
$statmnt -> execute();

//show that table is created 
echo "The Table has been creaetd";
}

?>
```